# Group data and subtract first and last value (or higher and lower value)

Tags: python, pandas

I got the db:

```
   pat  exp   t  wt
0  abc    1  10   0
1  abc    1  20   0
2  abc    1  30   0
3  dfg    2  20   0
4  dfg    3  15   0
5  dfg    3  30   0
6  dfg    2  40   0
7  hij    4  25   0
8  hij    4  50   0
```

And I want to change the value of "wt" column, by subtracting the first and last value of "t" for every "pat" and "exp", for example, for "pat"="dfg" and "exp"=3, the value of "wt" would be by subtracting 30-15. The desired output would be like:

```
   pat  exp   t   wt
0  abc    1  10   20
1  abc    1  20   20
2  abc    1  30   20
3  dfg    2  20   20
4  dfg    3  15   15
5  dfg    3  30   15
6  dfg    2  40   20
7  hij    4  25   25
8  hij    4  50   25
```

It may be the same by subtracting the higher and lower value for "t" of every "pat" and "exp", if the data is not ordered.
I tried with

```
for i in db["pat"]:
    for j in db["exp"]:
        db= db["t"].iloc[-1]-db["t"].iloc[0]
```

But nothing happens, and returns an error. Help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try `numpy` `ptp` with `transform`

```
df['wt']=df.groupby(['pat','exp']).t.transform(np.ptp)
df
   pat  exp   t  wt
0  abc    1  10  20
1  abc    1  20  20
2  abc    1  30  20
3  dfg    2  20  20
4  dfg    3  15  15
5  dfg    3  30  15
6  dfg    2  40  20
7  hij    4  25  25
8  hij    4  50  25
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about np.ptp  =)